The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/savoury1/ffmpeg4/ubuntu noble Release' does not have a Release file" on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
I recently tried to add the savoury1/ffmpeg4 PPA on my Ubuntu 24.04.1 (codenamed "noble") system to install an updated version of FFmpeg. However, when I run sudo apt update, I receive the following error:
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/savoury1/ffmpeg4/ubuntu noble Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

I understand this usually happens when a PPA doesn't support the specific Ubuntu release I'm using, but I'd like to know if there are any workarounds or alternatives. Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Changing the release name: I edited the PPA’s sources file to replace "noble" with "lunar" or "jammy," but I’m not sure if this is the right approach or if it could cause compatibility issues.
Removing the PPA: I considered removing it entirely, but I’d really like to get the latest FFmpeg version if possible.

Could anyone help me with any alternative methods to get an updated version of FFmpeg?
Thanks in advance for any guidance!
I'm also using an old linux-image because of issues in the latest image and I'm not able to delete the other kernel versions and set current on default


The workaround is to get the source code, and compile it yourself for your own machine, or upload it to your own created PPA (or Personal Package Archive) and have launchpad create it for whatever releases you specify (as it'll be your PPA; you can control that)
